# Can anyone identify this plant growing in a garden in North Cornwall, England?

Tags: identification, pests, pest-control

This over 1m tall, rigid upright plant is growing in a patch of bare earth in my Cornish  garden. No sign of flower buds yet. It has elongated, fine toothed, unstalked hairless leaves in opposite pairs growing up the slightly furry unridged stem, about 3 or 4cm apart. Pairs of branches grow out at on opposite sides at the position of the stem leaves, symmetrically, all the way up to the top. Looks a bit like Great Willowherb, but isn't. Have also ruled out Caper Spurge. The plant has put out a stolon and a new plant is now growing from it. Can anyone identify it please?

[image: Plant stands over 1m high. Plant behind is 8ft buddleia]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! And thank you for a well-phrased, detailed question! If you want to learn more about how the site works, I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help].

Comment: I'm torn (probably incorrectly) between a willowherb (of which there are umpteen species and varietes) and a buddleia. Please upload a photo of the flowers as soon as they appear. Are there other similar plants growing nearby in the wild?

Answer (score 1):

The leaves look a bit like *buddleia*  but they are usually more silvery, slightly serrated and slightly hairy, although I imagine they vary by variety. The ability to grow very rapidly in unexpected places also fits.